# Where can I upload replays to ask question about my mistakes?

Tags: starcraft-2

I would like to upload my replays to some StarCraft 2 replay portal in order to ask questions about my mistakes.

sc2replayed - doesn't upload replays anymore (in automatic mode it just put them into queue, in manual - I was not able to uploaad, gosugamers - not for "non-gosu" replays, I've found few others - they sucks (either can't register - looks like they have mistakes on the web site yet).

I could upload to some 'public' shared storage, but don't really like this idea.

Please advise the resource where I can upload replay. Would be good if it parses my replay and provide some statistical information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give these replay sites a try.

http://star2.org/
http://sc2rep.com/
http://replayfu.com/

EDIT: Star2.org has a small but active community where you can seek feedback and not be drowned in a sea of similar requests.

Answer (score 1):

I would not only depend on some *replay site*. The problem with this approach is that there are hundreds of new replays every day and your feedback will not be very good.

Try to upload your replay on a site like http://sc2rep.com/ and post a link on some good forum like [Teamliquid](http://www.teamliquid.net/) or if you are German you can try [InStarcraft](http://www.instarcraft.de).

Usually these forums have threads for these kind of requests, where you look at other replays and post comments and they help you with your problems.

This is not requested, but here still some tips how to spot your own mistakes in replays:

- Watch the whole replay and only look at your resources, if they go unintended beyond 800 identify the problem.
- Watch the whole replay and only look at your base / production facilities, if you stop production for a long period of time that is a problem.

Comment: Just don't forget to read the rules for the TL strategy section so your thread will live longer than 5 minutes :p

Comment: That's what I actually want. In fact, I've uploaded to the sc2rep.com 2 replays recently, how can I find them now? Search on my nick name doesn't find them... please advise.

Comment: I am not sure how you can search for a replay, it might take some time. Usually it takes about 5 minutes for your replay to be displayed in "Public Replays", as the site has to extract the information (APM etc.). You could go back and look for the specific date.

Answer (score 1):

Upload your replay here: http://drop.sc/replays ... it's very simple and easy to link to.

I recommend using http://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft2_class to get feedback on your replays. It's a lot more laid back than TL and you won't be crucified for not reading things. You could also post the replay here and I'd be happy to go through it, but that's probably against some sort of rule, so do it in a comment so it can't be closed.